# find non-existent value from oracle Table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a ORACLE Table from where I have to find the non existent data as well.

In the table 2nd column denotes the status of service, sometime few status will not appear, if the service is running fine. hence need a SQL which takes out the values

Table Columns & data are:-

```
Service Name, Status of Service, Count
ABCD, Available, 4
ABCD, Non Available, 5
XYZ, Non Available, 4
QWERTY, Available, 2
```

Please help in for a sql query to post output as below, if the first 2 column are unavailable, the count should be 0:-

```
Service Name, Status of Service, Count
ABCD, Available, 4
ABCD, Non Available, 5
XYZ, Available, 0
XYZ, Non Available, 4
QWERTY, Available, 2
QWERTY, Non Available, 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate all combinations of service and status with a `cross join` and `left join` the existing table on to that.

```
select serv.service_name, serv_stat.status_service, coalesce(t.countCol,0) 
from (select distinct service_name from tbl) serv 
cross join (select distinct status_service from tbl) serv_stat
left join tbl t on t.service_name = serv.service_name and serv_stat.status_service = t.status_service
```